# How to check two possibilities in an if statement in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to check two variables, `count` and `count1`, for equality with 2.

I tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
if [ $count -eq 2 || $count1 -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "Condition passsed"
fi
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That type of conditional doesn't recognize `||`. You either need to use `-o` (or), or use a `[[` test:

```
if [ $count -eq 2 -o $count1 -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "Condition passsed"
fi

if [[ $count -eq 2 || $count1 -eq 2 ]]; then
    echo "Condition passsed"
fi
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that `[[` is a bashism, not POSIX and also not present in `/bin/sh`, so use `if [ ... -o ...]` or `if [ ... ] || [...]` if you want more portability.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[[`:

```
if [[ $count -eq 2 || $count1 -eq 2 ]]; then echo "Condition passsed"; fi
```